# ionic cordova plugins and ionic.Platform.ready

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm not sure I have completely understood this [part](http://ionicframework.com/docs/angularjs/utils/platform/) of the ionic doc.

Does it means that where ever in my code I'm using a cordova plugin (controller or service) I always have to wrap it with inside a  ionic.platform.ready() block?

For example, in one of my controllers I need to stop a timer and cancel a notification:

```
$scope.stopTimer = function(index){
        $interval.cancel($scope.timers[index].interval);
        ionic.Platform.ready(function(){ 
            cordova.plugins.notification.local.cancel(index);
        }
    };
```

Is the ionic.Platform.ready necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if You want use **native** plugins you should use them after callback

`ionic.Platform.ready(callback)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried without it and it still works as expected... why it doesn't fail?

Comment: Maybe becaouse you are using this plugin when Platform is already ready. (for example action of some button)

But sometimes if you want use plugin on page startup event, platform could be not ready.

Comment: Ah yes indeed I was calling that function after a button. thanks this was very clear

Comment: Thats not an answer to the question. Which is no, you don't have to wrap it in a platform.ready event. Please adjust it so people don't have to read through all the comments

Comment: Now I'm confused. What is it the purpose of the ready block then?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `ionic.Platform.ready(callback)` is to be sure that the platform is **actually** ready but it's not a necessity, just a good practice because most of the time the platform is already ready.

Comment: It's true that it's usually ready, but load time can vary between devices and platforms.  I've forgotten to wrap a plugin which seemed to work fine until i tested on another device where it magically failed.  It's just better to wrap it all.